# '#empty_option' not working for nested select list

Tags: forms

I have a form with several select lists, the select lists that are not nested show the "#empty_option" as expected, but the ones in a nested container do not work.

Expected output: the "client type" and all the "address type" selects have empty options.

Actual result: the "client type" has the empty option, the "address type" selects do not have the empty option and default to the "Range" option.

I cannot find anything wrong with my syntax.  Is there something I am missing?  Is this a known issue with Drupal 10?  Is there a workaround?

```
<?php

//code to get $clientInfo from the database

$form = [
  'ClientType' => [
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => $this->t('Client Type'),
    '#options' => [
      'annual' => $this->t('Annual Subscriber'),
      'coorporate' => $this->t('Corporate Sponsor'),
      'institution' => $this->t('Educational Institution'),
      'legacy' => $this->t('Legacy Member'),
      'non-legacy' => $this->t('Non-Legacy Member'),
    ],
    '#default_value' => (isset($clientInfo->ClientType) ? $clientInfo->ClientType : ''),
    '#empty_option' => $this->t('Please select a client type'),
  ],
];

//code to get $IPs info from the DB

foreach($IPs as $i => $IP){
  
//code to get $thisType from the DB
  
  $rows[$i] = [
    'IP Address Line' => [
      'data' => [
        '#type' => 'container',
        [
          '#markup' => $i,
        ],
        [
          '#type' => 'hidden',
          '#name' => "IPv4[$i][IPv4ID]",
          '#value' => (isset($IP->IPv4ID) ? $IP->IPv4ID : NULL),
        ],
      ],
    ],
    'Address Type' => [
      'data' => [
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#options' => [
          1 => $this->t('Range'),
          2 => $this->t('CIDR'),
          3 => $this->t('Single IP or Wildcard'),
          'DELETE' => $this->t('Delete this Entry!'),
        ],
        '#empty_option' => 'SELECT',
        '#empty_value' => '',
        '#title' => t('IP Entry #@i\'s type', ['@i' => $i]),
        '#title_display' => 'attribute',
        '#default_value' => $thisType,
        '#required' => TRUE,
        '#attributes' =>[
          'name' => "IPv4[$i][AddressType]",
          'id' => "IPv4-{$i}-AddressType",
        ],
      ],
    ],
  ];
}


$form['IPv4DIV'] = [
  '#type' => 'container',
  '#states' => [
    'visible' => [
      '#edit-allowedauthentications-3' => [
        'checked' => TRUE
      ]
    ]
  ],
  'IPv4Listing' => [
    '#theme' => 'table',
    '#header' => ['IP Address Line', 'Address Type', 'IP Info'],
    '#rows' => $rows,
    '#attributes' => [
      'class' => [
        'table',
        'table-responsive',
        'table-striped',
        'table-hover',
      ],
    ],
  ],
];

$form['actions'] = [
    '#type' => 'actions',
    'submit' => [
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => $this->t('Save Client Information'),
    ],
];
```

Comment: Does it change if you remove the `#empty_value` line?

Comment: No, it doesn't matter whether `#empty_value` is there or not.

Comment: I also tried `'#type'=>'table'` instead of `'#theme'=>'table'`, same result.